# Sinch instant messaging: synchronising messages across devices with differing clocks

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

Using the [sinch instant messaging for android](https://www.sinch.com/docs/instant-message/android/), how to sync so that messages appear in the correct order, if two devices have different clocks?

When I read [the docs](http://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/reference/com/sinch/android/rtc/messaging/Message.html#getTimestamp()) for `Message#getTimestamp()`, they state that it "returns the server side timestamp of the Message", which seems promising. It did not work, though: in practice, it appears that `onMessageSent()` is called with the local time while `onIncomingMessage()` is called with the server time.

Imagine that device 1 and device 2 have different clocks and are chatting with eachother, and that device1 is ahead of device2. For example, device1 has 7:15 while device2 has 7:00. The server time is also 7:00. These were my findings:

- device1 sends "First message!"
- device1: `onMessageSent()` is triggered. `m.getTimestamp()` returns 7:15 (the local time for device1)
- device2: `onIncomingMessage()` is triggered.  `m.getTimestamp()` returns 7:00 (the server time, and the local time for device2)

Shouldn't `getTimestamp()` always return server-side time? Am I missing something?

Comment: I can confirm that its a bug on our side,